# Ask for a possibly cached password in Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
systemd-ask-password --keyname=domain:pw --accept-cached Password:
```

from Expect. This command works fine, from a terminal, to either return the cached password if it already exists or prompt for it and *then* cache it. However, I have not managed to figure out a way to make it interact with `expect`.

```
send "systemd-ask-password --keyname=domain:pw --accept-cached Password:\r"
```

produces no output to interact with, and

```
spawn "systemd-ask-password --keyname=domain:pw --accept-cached Password:\r"
```

says `": no such file or directory...` which implies the spawned process is not even using the same keyring.

I'd be happy enough to use the lower level `keyctl`, but I'm having the same results with that

What is the correct syntax to make `systemd-ask-password` or `keyctl` prompt on the tty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to run the command using the tty that you are currently in. This can be done using `exec`.  For example, the following shell interaction (`****` is where I typed `none`):

```sh
$ cat <<\! >myprog
set pw [exec systemd-ask-password --keyname=domain:pw --accept-cached Password:]
send_user "you said pw=$pw\n"
!
$ expect myprog
Password: ****
you said pw=none
$ expect myprog
you said pw=none
```

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. I haven't seen the `set variable [...]` syntax before.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to do that as a stand-alone thing to run as a spawned subprocess, I'd anticipate launching it with something like this:

```
spawn systemd-ask-password --keyname=domain:pw --accept-cached Password:
```

The only reason for `send`ing that would be if there's a shell being controlled where we want it to carry that out for us (perhaps because it is going to be running on a remote computer).

There will probably be a need for automating the handling of the possible asking for the password and managing the result. Of course. But for testing, put an `interact` command after that `spawn` so that you can talk to the subprocess (as-if-it-was) directly.

Comment: As I said, I used `spawn`. It doesn't even seem to look in the right keyring, but nevertheless it didn't prompt, either.